# GraphQL Design: May edge have own subedges (connections, relationships)?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-relay

Let's say that a user creates an order with products in a e-shop, but ordered products have their options to be selected during order process. So user has to select products with some options to buy. 
In graphql there are three types: `Product`, `ProductOption` and `Order`.

```
type Product implements Node {
   id: ID!
   name: String!
   options: [ProductOptionsConnection!]!
}

type ProductOption implements Node {
   id: ID!
   name: String!
   product: Product!
}

type ProductOptionsConnection {
  edges: [ProductOptionEdge!]!
  totalCount: Int!
  ...
}

type ProductOptionEdge {
  node: ProductOption!
}

type Order implements Node {
   id: ID!
   createdAt: DateTime!
   products: OrderProductsConnection!
}
```

**The question is: what is the best approach of relationships between order, products and selected options?**

1:

```
type OrderProductsConnection {
   edges: [OrderProductEdge!]!
   totalCount: Int!
   ...
}

type OrderProductEdge {
   node: Product!
   selectedOptions: [OrderProductOptionsConnection!]!
   addedAt: DateTime
}

type OrderProductOptionsConnection {
   edges: [OrderProductOptionEdge!]!
   totalCount: Int!
   ...
}

type OrderProductOptionEdge {
   node: ProductOption
}
```

2:

```
type OrderProductsConnection {
   edges: [OrderProductEdge!]!
   totalCount: Int!
   ...
}

type OrderProductEdge {
  node: OrderProduct!
}

type OrderProduct {  // implements Node??
  product: Product!
  selectedOptions: OrderProductOptionsConnection!
  addedAt: DateTime!
}

type OrderProductOptionsConnection {
  edges: [OrderProductOptionEdge]!
}

type OrderProductOptionEdge {
   node: OrderProductOption!
}

type OrderProductOption { // implements Node??
   option: ProductOption!
   ...
}
```